# PHP force instance of Closure, sort of

Tags: php, types, closures, anonymous-function

To quote PHP:

> Anonymous functions are currently implemented using the **[Closure](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.classes.php#reserved.classes.closure)** class. This is an implementation detail and should not be relied upon.

Now, that said, the following checks are deemed unreliable:

```
function myFunction(Closure $callback){}

if(!($callback instanceof Closure)){}
```

Which brings us to using `is_callable()`. This is fine, however if one *requires* a true "**closure**", (*as an argument, or what-such*) then `is_callable()` isn't strict enough. The following of course dumps `bool(true)` for each:

```
function myFunction(){}

class MyClass{
    public function __invoke(){}
}

var_dump(is_callable('myFunction'));
var_dump(is_callable(new MyClass));
```

How, without relying on the `Closure` class (*given is **is** in fact unreliable*) can one strictly identify a "**closure**"?

---

### Update

It has occurred to me I was falling in the direction of bad design. However, despite this question being answered, I think it would be appreciated if anyone could suggest answers to the posed question, if not purely for the academic element of it.

### Update (*again*)

Since the release of PHP 5.4 (*awhile ago now*) the `Closure` type is no longer an "implementation detail", and can be relied on. `function f(Closure $g) { }` is all good.

Comment: "strictly identify a Closure". Wouldn't that be at direct odds with the concept of an anonymous function?

Comment: Why do you *need* an instance of Closure?

Comment: @lonesomeday - If user-code is passing `__invoke`-able objects or function names by string, it will convolute the module I'm working on, and it's intended purpose.

Comment: @George Cummins - No, I wouldn't think so. By "strictly identify a closure", I mean identify that it's *not* an `__invoke`-able object or string function name.

Comment: I'm with George: If you really need an object of an specific type, why you don't create it (see `interface`, e.g. `interface Action { public function exec($arg);}`)? Thats much more OOPish. I cannot imagine one single purpose, why it should make sense to restrict callables to a single kind... I don't know, what you are trying to achieve, but maybe there will be situations, where a single closure gets much too complex and packing its functionality into a callable class makes the code much cleaner.

Comment: @KingCrunch **+1** to you and @George. That would make the most sense. I just had an epiphany.

Comment: I recently had a situation in which parameters could be either literals or evaluable. Iterating through the collection, I needed to strictly test for a closure, because `floor` was acceptable as a literal, even though it's callable. Oddly, `is_object($x) && get_class($x) === 'Closure'` was the way to go. It succeeded where `$x instanceof Closure` failed. Cool huh :)

Comment: It seems that they changed their mind about the implementation detail:

'Anonymous functions, implemented in PHP 5.3, yield objects of this type. This fact used to be considered an implementation detail, but it can now be relied upon.'

http://php.net/manual/en/class.closure.php

So you checks are now reliable.

Comment: @NeilE.Pearson I would think `is_object($x) && is_callable($x)` would be more appropriate in your particular use case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only time you should be typing arguments is when there is something about that particular class which you *need*. Even then, you are better off with use of an interface. That is just good OOP design.

I cannot fathom the existence of a situation where there would be a benefit to forcing something to be a Closure. The only thing which should matter, in that case, is whether or not the parameter "is_callable". Even if it were possible to accomplish your goal, I would argue that it is unexpected functionality of a framework and therefore anti-pattern.

Comment: Thanks @cwallenpoole - When you put it that way, you're right. If the client-code is trying to do something odd, that'll come out in the woodwork anyways. And if they create a fancy hack to support otherwise unsupported functionality by passing an `__invoke`-able object, then I should retrofit the application to support their findings. Complete change of heart happening here. Thanks again.

Comment: @cwallenpoole, There's benefit in not using is_callable. I would say is_callable is too wide. It accepts a *ton* of things and this may make bugs harder to catch, for the same reason lenient code make bugs harder to catch than strict style.

Comment: @Pacerier If he's creating a framework, then using "is_callable" seems like it would be a sufficient check, though. I see not problems with "Is the thing I'm about to call callable? No? Then let them no about it. Otherwise, call it."

Answer (score 6):

It seems that PHP developers changed their mind about Closure class being an implementation detail:

> Anonymous functions, implemented in PHP 5.3, yield objects of this type. This fact used to be considered an implementation detail, **but it can now be relied upon**.

See http://php.net/manual/en/class.closure.php

Therefore you should consider now your checks are reliable:

```
function myFunction(Closure $callback){}

if(!($callback instanceof Closure)){}
```

Comment: I like it! :) Good find @Radu

Comment: perfect, I was having the same dilemma :)

Answer (score 2):

Static / Global functions would be a string, and OOP callables are an array... So couldn't you:

```
if ( ! is_string( $var ) && ! is_array( $var ) && is_callable( $var ) )
```

I too needed strict Closures. Why? My DB abstraction layer has its queries / configurations segregated from the rest of my application. I've implemented Tier / Shard features, where a key represents a DB which can then be loaded on demand (or was previously loaded.) This key could be for example 'default' and if such a function existed on the global scope (doubtful as I code mostly OOP,) I would NOT want it to be called and instead use the key.

Continuing the above code:

```
{
    $var = $var( $inputs );
}
```

$inputs are values used for query generation, allowing the Closure to return a different key based on its values. Hence, with proper design techniques, Sharding is now possible.

Of course my situation is irrelevant, but I hope it may help another.

Comment: Similar but a little shorter: if (is_object($conditions) && is_callable($conditions))